# CSS preserve aspect ratio but fill parent div

Tags: html, css, less

Basically, I have an image that I want to mask with a circle.

```
<div class="thumbnail-mask">
  <img class="thumbnail-pic" src="/image.jpeg">
</div>
```

The CSS (I'm using LESS) is pretty simple:

```
.thumbnail-mask {
  width: @circleSize;
  height: @circleSize;
  border-radius: @circleSize/2;
  -webkit-border-radius: @circleSize/2;
  -moz-border-radius: @circleSize/2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've figured out how to center the image within the parent both vertically and horizontally

```
.thumbnail-pic {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  // width: 100%;
  // height: auto;
  height:auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But now the issue is height and width.

If I try `height:100%; width:100%;` the aspect ratio is changed.

If height > width, then I want `width: 100%; height: auto;`. If width > height, I want `height: 100%; width: auto`. This way, the circle is entirely filled out. But this doesn't seem to be possible. I've tried setting `min-width:100%; min-height:100%` but then without setting the height or the width, the image is way too big.

Comment: did you play with max-height and max-width, but setting a speicif width and height to the container's deminsions? I think that's how I accomplished this same goal

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle For Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rdW8N/3/)

One solution is to use jquery to set image width and height based on the aspect ratio

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").each(function () {
        // Calculate aspect ratio and store it in HTML data- attribute
        var aspectRatio = $(this).width() / $(this).height();
        $(this).data("aspect-ratio", aspectRatio);

        // Conditional statement
        if (aspectRatio > 1) {
            // Image is landscape
            $(this).css({
                height: "100%"
            });
        } else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
            // Image is portrait
            $(this).css({
                width: "100%"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously this isn't quite as elegant to pure css methods, but will probably end up being more reliable

Comment: This is basically what I have going right now. But it really slows down the browser. Especially when I have a bunch of these and there are a bunch of reactive call backs when they render.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying another way is to adjust the html structure a little and do the image as a background-image then use cover. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdW8N/4/)

Comment: There is a fiddle link in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block;` in `.thumbnail-mask` should wrap the `<img>` inside of it