# How to fit whole image in to div which have his dimensions

Tags: jquery, css, image, image-resizing

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <small>Original picture size is 876x493, I resize it to:</small>
    <div class = "property">
      <img src = "http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Leisure/2009/876/493/big-house-small-house.png?ve=1&tl=1"/>
    </div>
    <small>Result I want to get (in another way):</small>
    <div class = "property">
      <img style = "max-width: 147%" src = "http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Leisure/2009/876/493/big-house-small-house.png?ve=1&tl=1"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/40ay7uco/

I want to reduce my image to fit it in div.
How I can do it with jquery or css, without mannualy writing like I did before.

p.s. I want to keep width:height ratio

Comment: Set it as background https://jsfiddle.net/40ay7uco/1/

Comment: Instead of max-height / max-width, simply use height / width. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/40ay7uco/2/

Comment: @NenadVracar, thanks for advice, but properties will be displayed by php code, so this way is not suitable for me

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I want to keep width:height ratio

Comment: @zhinyz Maybe you could do something like this and generate image url in `data-background` attr with php https://jsfiddle.net/40ay7uco/6/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `background-image` with **JQuery** and use `background-size: cover;` on `property` div

```js
$('.property').each(function() {
  var background = $(this).data('background');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+background+')');
});
```

```css
.property {
    border: 3px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaaaaa;
    width: 270px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <small>Original picture size is 876x493, I resize it to:</small>
    <div class = "property" data-background="http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Leisure/2009/876/493/big-house-small-house.png?ve=1&tl=1">
    </div>
    
    <div class = "property" data-background="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    
    <div class = "property" data-background="http://placehold.it/700x500/ffffff/000000">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```html
<div id="img" style="width:50px;height:50px">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="image" style="width:100%" />
</div>
```

First, give that div appropriate size as you want and then give your Image 100% width.

Answer (score 2):

You were setting max dimensions for your image, so it would only appear on it's own resolution. Letting the width be an automatic size will keep the ratio.

This should work:

```css
.property {
    border: 3px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaaaaa;
    width: 270px;
    height: 200px; /*This will keep aspect ratio for your image*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
.property img {
    height: 100%; /*This will keep aspect ratio for your image*/
    width: auto;  /*Not necessary since this is the default value*/
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "property">
      <img src = "http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Leisure/2009/876/493/big-house-small-house.png?ve=1&tl=1"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the image is going outside the div even tho it cant be seen.

[image]

Comment: I want to keep width:height ratio

Comment: Oh I see, let me check

Comment: Tanks, it works, but only with images which width is greater than height. Maybe you know solution for both image types?

Comment: In this case you would need Javascript w/ Jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944354/css-preserve-aspect-ratio-but-fill-parent-div

Answer (score 2):

I think **[`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)** is what you're looking for. Be aware of the browser support [tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50kek8bb/)**

```css
.object-fit {
  width: 200px; /*any size*/
  height: 200px; /*any size*/
  object-fit: cover; /*magic*/
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaaaaa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img class="object-fit" src="http://i.imgur.com/4fYhkO2.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want keep dimension the width of image should auto.

```
.property {
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaaaaa;
  width: 270px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.property img {
  max-width: 100%;   /*Should remove*/
  max-height: 100%;  /*Should remove*/
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I edited your code. You can checkout https://jsfiddle.net/dtv6bk75/